# What are some good methods to learn how to pronounce the letter V

Tags: pronunciation

My friend has a problem pronouncing V. It sounds just like a W. I'm looking for some good methods to help him pronounce V. Bear in mind I have no language teaching experience.

Comment: It's not a clear cut answer but you could try work on the emphasis of the sound (*vh*) as that is a common sound when we pronounce the letter V in normal scenarios. People that pronounce V as W commonly switch around the pronunciations of the (*vh*) = v noise with the (*wh*) = w noise.

Comment: What is your native language?  Different languages pronounce "B", "F", "U", "V", and "W" differently.

Comment: Are they having trouble with the letter on its own ('vee') or when it's used in a word ('vuh')?

Comment: @Jasper His native language is Mandarin.

Comment: @Damien He has problems using it in a word. 'Vote' sounds like 'Wote'.

Comment: This is almost an impossible question to answer because this is an asynchronous medium, which is bad enough, but even more so, it's a written medium, and you're asking about a verbal problem, and one that can almost definitely only be solved by face-to-face coaching. My two cents: have him make the /f/ sound first by telling him to put his teeth on his bottom lip, then add voicing afterward. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Does your friend have access to a person who is a native speaker of English?  For example, you, a teacher, or a paid tutor in one of the learn-English-over-Skype services?  If so, they can tell your friend whether his pronunciation is correct.  They can also tell your friend which "real" English letter his "V"s sound like.

Fortunately, the letter "V" can be pronounced more-or-less continuously.  This means that if you can tell your friend exactly how to position the various parts of his mouth, and whether to voice the sound, your friend can practice saying the letter "V".  A mirror can help.

Here are the relevant body parts:

- Lower jaw.  How far down is it from the tips of the top front teeth to the tips of the bottom front teeth?  How far back (or forward) is it from the tips of the top front teeth to the tips of the bottom front teeth?
- Upper lip.  Is it touching the lower lip?  Is it puckered?  How much of the top front teeth are showing?
- Lower lip.  Is it touching the upper lip?  Is it puckered?  How much of the bottom front teeth are showing?
- Tongue.  Is the tip of the tongue touching something?  Exactly what spot is it touching?  Is the tongue curled?  In what direction?
- Vocal cords.  If your friend puts his hand over his Adam's apple (larynx), does he feel a buzzing sound?

I am an adult with an American accent.  When I pronounce the letter "V":

- My lower jaw does not touch my upper jaw.
- The tips of my lower front teeth are about 1/8 inch (3 mm) below the tips of my upper front teeth.
- The tips of my lower front teeth are about 3/16 inch (4 mm) back (closer to my neck) from the tips of my upper front teeth.
- My lips are not puckered.
- My upper lip does not touch my lower lip.  The bottom of my upper lip is about 1/8 inch (3 mm) above the tips of my upper front teeth.
- My lower lip touches the tips of my upper front teeth.
- My tongue is not curled.
- The tip of my tongue is lightly pressed against the bottom half of my lower front teeth.
- My vocal cords (in my larynx) are vibrating.  If I do everything above, and vibrate my vocal cords, I pronounce an English "V".  If I do everything above, but do not vibrate my vocal cords, I pronounce an English "F".

The difference in how I pronounce "V" versus "W" is mostly in how I position my lips.  I slightly pucker my lips when pronouncing "W".  I also move both lips down when pronouncing "W":  The upper lip is about 1 mm below the tips of my upper front teeth, and the lower lip is about 3 mm below the tips of my upper front teeth.